# How to apply 'case when' result to the where condition in SQL 2008 query

Tags: sql-server-2008, case

I'm working with the 'case when' statement in my query and doing some experiments. I tried to search for this problem but I am unable to put it in words.

my query problem example:

```
Select (a really long case when statement) as result from tablename where result=1
```

is there any way to also put 'result' to the 'where' condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. The easiest way is to use `CROSS APPLY (VALUES...`

```sql
SELECT v.MyValue
FROM tablename
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (complex_expression_here) ) v(MyValue)
WHERE v.MyValue = 1
```

You could also place it in a derived table, but I find that more verbose

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT complex_expression_here AS MyValue
    FROM tablename
) t
WHERE v.MyValue = 1
```